# Use CASE to update some records

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

```
Private Sub Command204_Click()

Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb

db.Execute "UPDATE Table1 SET Test =(CASE WHEN (Test = 'A') THEN 'B' WHEN (Test ='B' THEN 'A') ELSE Test END ) WHERE Test IN ('A','B')"

db.Close


End Sub
```

Getting error when I press the button. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access' flavor of SQL does not support `CASE` expressions.  You could use `IIF()` here instead:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Test = IIF(Test = "A", "B", "A")
WHERE Test IN ("A", "B");
```

Comment: `its not working` <-- this is not feedback which lets me update my answer.  _What_ exactly isn't working?

Comment: can you read out my equation again. becoz i made some changes now. please

Comment: Actually i trying to update  'A' in the place of 'B' and the same 'B' in the place of 'A'.